# video behind image makes image opaque/de-saturated

Tags: html, css

Alright.. I'm struggling with this one..

I've got an image with a transparent "hole" cut in it, and I place a video behind it. However, when the video is there, the image becomes sort of.. de-saturated.

Here is the CSS

```
  .header {
      position: relative;
  }

  .header img{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .header video{
      position: absolute;
      width: 168px;
      left: 553px;
      top: 109px;
      z-index: 1;
  }
```

And the markup

```
<div class="span12 header"><img src="img/screenshot-final.png"/><video src="img/video/video-final.mp4"></video></div>
```

I'm not sure why the video would effect the image since its dimensions are fit to the hole in the image. However, setting display:none on the video "fixes" the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure this is unavoidable, have you thought about placing the image ontop of the video to fit the hole with an appropriate z-index. Not ideal but I think the de-saturation is standard for a video overlaying an image!

EDIT: try putting you video in a div tag and the putting your image inside a div tag inside that div! then use absolute positioning to rectify the positioning! this should sort you out

EDIT:

```
<div class="span12 header">
<video src="img/video/video-final.mp4"></video>
<div id="image">
<img src="img/screenshot-final.png"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but of course you would have to make sure the overlaying image is cut to exactly fit the size of the hole

Comment: Oh man! unavoidable? That's terrible.  I don't quite understand your suggestion though. The image is on top of the video via z-index.

Comment: sh ok, I sm not paying wnough attention clearly, I saw that you had an image behind a video but now I see its the other way around, thats a whole other story, let me look again

Comment: Something like this? <div id="vid-container"> <video../> <div id="img-container"><img.../></div>

Comment: @CambridgeMike almost check mine above

Comment: HAH! please do explain.. what on earth is going on here? Links to references would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think... videos take preference over images... so incase in a div, and the div properties will take preference as per your CSS. just google for further info... no references go for a google, it was a educated guess of an answer really!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9381/discussion-between-cambridgemike-and-phil)